# can't stop process when it running on django

Tags: django, multithreading, python-3.x, data-structures, while-loop

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="POST" name="form">  
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div>
                <input type ="submit" value = "start" name = "start"  >

                <input type ="submit" value = "stop" name = "stop" >

            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is views.py file using threading, i also tried without thread but when process start in django server, it can not stop or kill.

```
#views.py

import time
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
import threading
class IndexView(generic.TemplateView):
   template_name = 'demo/index.html'
   def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
       flag1 = request.POST.get("start")
       if flag1 == "start":
           flag = "start"
       flag1 = request.POST.get("stop")
       if flag1 == "stop":
           flag = "stop"
       def job_test(arg):
           t = threading.currentThread()
           while getattr(t, "do_run", True):
               print ("working on %s" % arg)
               time.sleep(1)
           print("Stopping as you wish.")
       t = threading.Thread(target=job_test, args=("task",))
       if flag == "stop":
           time.sleep(10)
       if flag == "start":
           time.sleep(0)
       t.join()
```

without thread

```
class IndexView(generic.TemplateView):
   template_name = 'demo/index.html'
   def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
       flag1 = request.POST.get("start")
       if flag1 == "start":
           flag = "start"
       flag1 = request.POST.get("stop")
       if flag1 == "stop":
           flag = "stop"
       def job():
           print("Processing Start..")
       while flag == "start":
           #job()
           print ("job() call...")
           demo_var1 = request.POST.get("stop")
           if demo_var1 == "stop":
               flag = "stop"
               print("This is while flag inside : ",flag)
               break
           time.sleep(10)
```

I want to start process when user press start button from browser, stop that process from pressing stop button.

i did not understand why code can't break in while.

please help me to find solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normally, for long tasks you'd use an entirely separate process with e.g. [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't break in the `while` statement because the function doesn't redurn (gets stuck in the `while` statement. Clicking on the button will instantiate again the `IndexView`class.

You'd need to make `flag` a global variable so it's the same value for all instances. This is really bad. A site effect is e.g. that all users who have something running (in the while loop) will exit :)

Comment: i am trying to stop process  via variable in mongodb as a flag, when i press on stop then value of flag(mongodb)variable is changes true to false, i am working with multiple process, how can i check  value of flag (mongodb)variable in while loop?

Comment: Yes, you can check the value in the loop, but you need to go to another view to change the DB value. I'd go with a `LoopView` (where you have the loop) and a `ButtonView` where you trigger the DB change. you could have the HTML from `LoopView` with a `POST` to the `ButtonView`.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple process you can store flag in DB and when you want to stop separate process then change flag.